# Terse way to get remainder of an iterable (like an array)

Tags: javascript

I want to get the remainder of an iterable like an array. Like so:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var brr = arr.slice(1);
```

But is there a terser way (maybe using destructuring assignment?).

Comment: Question added for my future reference.

Comment: `var brr = ['a', 'b', 'c'].slice( ... )`  ... Still, I've a question: _why ?_

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is:

```
var [,...brr] = arr; // ['b', 'c']
```

Multiple elision also works:

```
var [,,...brr] = arr; // ['c']
```

Comment: What about for a different value for `.slice`, eg `arr.slice(3)`?

Comment: This answer is the extent of my current knowledge. Please edit if you have additional information.

Comment: @BenAston you need to add `...` to have an uniform answer. Then the number of `,` determines how many elements are picked